# squid + pfsense user authentication

Tags: authentication, squid, pfsense

I'm having a very strange problem with squid 3 and pfSense. Since I'm using a community created squid3 package for pfSense I'm not willing to rule out the possibility that it's a bug in the pfSense implementation. With that said, here's the problem.

I have basic "local" authentication set up, with 3 users defined: "admin", "test", and "myname." The only one that seems to work is "admin." I can log in with "admin" any any browser, and it works as intended, including all my filters, etc. Neither of the two other users work at all. It acts as if they aren't there. I also tried adding "administrator" and "admin2" accounts. "adminstrator" works, "admin2" doesn't. I have opened the squid password file to confirm that all the accounts are there. If I can think of any other synonyms for "administrator" I will try them.

Comment: We need to look at the squid config at least, on its authentication part. Post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this to work either, so what I did was setup the FreeRadius package on pfSense and then configured that to be the authentication backend for Squid, then I was able to login with the user I created on FreeRadius.

Just set Freeradius up to listen on port 1812 and then set the radius server in the Squid configuration to 127.0.0.1